# How to find the derivative of this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \int_0^{\cos x}t^2 \, dt$$

I computed and got $f'(x) = - \cos^2(x) \sin(x)$. I checked the answer in the book and I got this wrong. But I think I did this correctly. I used part 1 of FTC to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Your answer looks good to me. Perhaps the answer in the book is equivalent to yours, for example, using a trigonometric identity.

Comment: What is the answer in the book?

Comment: it is sin^2(x)cos(x);

Comment: The book is wrong ;-)

Comment: good to know :)

Comment: As a sanity check: for small positive $x$, you have $\cos x$ slightly below $1$ and decreasing, so $f(x)$ is positive and decreasing, so $f'(x)$ is negative for small positive $x$.  By contrast  $\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$ would be positive for small positive $x$ so cannot be equal to $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $$I=\int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \, dt$$ where $a$ is a constant, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
$$\frac{dI}{dx}=f(g(x))\, g'(x)$$ In you case where $g(x)=\cos(x)$ and $f(t)=t^2$, this leads to 
$$\frac{dI}{dx}=-\sin(x)\, \cos(x)^2$$

Answer (score 21):

Note that:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(t)\,dt = G\bigl(b(x)\bigr)-G\bigl(a(x)\bigr) \\
f'(x) &= g\bigl(b(x)\bigr)\cdot b'(x)-g\bigl(a(x)\bigr)\cdot a'(x)
\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_0^{\cos x}t^2 \, dt=G(\cos x)-G(0) \\
f'(x)&=(\cos x)^2\cdot (\cos x)'-(0)^2\cdot 0' \\
&=\cos^2x \cdot (-\sin x) \\
&=-\cos^2x\cdot \sin x
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to *explain* the FTC so that the OP can perhaps walk away with new *understanding* rather than another item to memorize which s/he has probably already seen anyways

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor, thank you for commenting, editing and upvoting. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
y & = \int_0^{\cos x} t^2\, dt \\[10pt]
y & = \int_0^u t^2 \, dt & u & = \cos x \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{du} & = u^2 & \frac{du}{dx} & = -\sin x \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \\[10pt]
& = u^2 \cdot(-\sin x) \\[10pt]
& = (\cos x)^2(-\sin x).
\end{align}
So your result is correct.

However, in order to know whether it was correctly graded, we would have to see exactly how the problem was stated. For example, if there was some standing instruction to the class to mention the chain rule explicitly each time it is used, then omitting to do that could count against you, and there are lots of other things like that that we might not know about without further information.

Answer (score 4):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus states that if
$$f(x) = \int_{a}^{g(x)} h(t)~{\rm d}t$$
where $a$ is any constant, then
$$f'(x) = h(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$
Using this with the integral, $f(x) = f( x)$, $g(x) = \cos x$, and $h(x) = t^2$.  We may now plug in these values. $ g'(x)=-\sin x$
$$f'(x) = -\sin(x)\cos^2(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

The direct method:

$$f(x)=\int_0^{\cos x}t^2\,dt=\left[\frac{t^3}3\right]_0^{\cos x}=\frac13\cos^3x$$ and using the chain rule $$f'(x)=\frac13\cdot3\cos^2x(-\sin x)-0=-\sin x\cos^2x$$ so you are correct!

Comment: There is no $-\frac{1}{3}$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: @Minethlos Thanks for spotting the typo!